# Splitting a long string at every / in lua

Tags: lua

So I am making a function in lua where i wan't it to split a string at every "/" so for example:

local s = "Hello/GoodBye/Hi"

then i want it to split and input it to a table so it will look something like this:

Hello

GoodBye

Hi

This is my attempt but it doesn't really work:

```
local STR = "Hello/GoodBye/Hi"
strings = {}
for q,string in STR:gmatch("([/])(.-)%1") do
    table.insert(strings, string)
end
```

That just returns:

Hello

Hi

Comment: Try it with ```gsub()``` - A good start could be: ```STR:gsub('([%w])([/])','%1\n')```

Answer (score 0):

> That just returns:
>
> Hello
>
> Hi

When I run your code there is only a single element in `strings` which is `"GoodBye"`.

The easiest way is to match anything that is not a `/` as in `"[^/]+"`.

Also naming a variable `string` is not a good idea. You're shadowing Lua`s string library.